# Insert Paypal payment date in database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, paypal

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.. I want to add a Paypal "buy now" button on my website and when a user pays I want to save the date they paid into the database using mysql.

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll need to do is create a PayPal IPN script, which will cause PayPal to call upon a PHP script on your server every time you receive a payment. [The full details are available on PayPal's website](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro), but here's an overview of how it works:

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is
>   a message service that notifies you of
>   events related to PayPal transactions.
>   You can use it to automate back-office
>   and administrative functions, such as
>   fulfilling orders, tracking customers,
>   and providing status and other
>   information related to a transaction
>
> You detect and process IPN messages
>   with a listener, sometimes called a
>   handler, which is a script or program
>   that you write. It waits for messages
>   and passes them to various back-end or
>   administrative processes that respond
>   the messages. PayPal provides sample
>   code that you can modify to implement
>   a listener that detects IPN messages.
>
> The actions to take when your listener
>   is notified of an event are specific
>   to your needs. Examples of the kinds
>   of actions you might take when your
>   listener receives an IPN message
>   include the following:
>
> Trigger order fulfillment or enable
>   media downloads when a check clears or
>   a payment is made Update your list of
>   customers Update accounting records
>   Create specialized “to do” lists based
>   on the kind of event You are typically
>   notified of events by email as well,
>   but the IPN message service enables
>   you to automate your response to
>   events. The following diagram shows
>   how events can occur and how PayPal
>   responds with IPN messages that it
>   sends to your listener:

[image: IPN]